# Not able to add a new column to my csv file

Tags: c#, csv

Below is my csv file format,now i want add new colomn between 1st and 2nd while parsing,
Current format :

```
1  file1-11  Mon
2  file2-02  tue
3  file3-21  wed
```

Expected format :

```
1  11  file1  mon
2  02  file2  tue
3  21  file3  wed
```

This is my code sample to read and split the csv file

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"D:FileWatcher/File_A.csv"))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    var values = line.Split(',').ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: so, \*scratch\* head, which part is adding the new column? anyway, given `values` is a `List`, you can use [`Insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=net-7.0) to add stuff in the middle of the `List`. something along the line of `values.Insert(1, "new-column");`. though looking at your example it seems you wanted to move stuff around instead of just adding new column - some requirement are glossed over? also, don't forget you have to write them back to the file.

Comment: Just loop through a stream doesn't mean change it. Where is the code that changes at least something?

Comment: Is it just me - or are there no commas to separate that example text?

Answer (score 0):

Does the following code do what you want ?
First split each line of code on both the space char & the '-', then reorder the output.

```
char [] sep = { '-', ' ' };
using (var reader = new StreamReader(@"D:FileWatcher/File_A.csv"))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        var values = line.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        Console.WriteLine($"{values[0]} {values[2]} {values[1]} {values[3]}");
    }
}
```

If you want to output to another file, the use a StreamWriter (or File) in place of the Console output.